# What is the limit for 3G marketplace downloads?

Tags: wifi, store, 3g

When I am trying to download some of the bigger apps/games, marketplace blocks the download until the phone has WiFi connection available. What is the limit for this? 10, 50, 100 MB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is 20 MB

When the download size is larger than 20 MB and you are connected on a 3g network you'll receive the "Attention required" message.

If you connect to wifi you can tap the attention required message and press retry.

source: [Microsoft WP7 Download apps and games FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/apps/download-apps-and-games-faq.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Has been increased to 50 MB if you are running tango 7.5. Apps above 50 MB can be downloaded with WiFi or PC connection only.

Comment: Tested on lumia 710